# A good place to start learning writing apps for the iphone?

Tags: iphone, app-store

I was wondering what would be the steps I need to follow if I am just an individual looking to write my own apps and get it approved by apple to feature on their store. Also, is it just objective-c I need to learn or what other skills would I require ?

What would be a good tutorial or a place to start ? What are the tools I require? I found [this](http://www.readwriteweb.com/archives/13_tools_for_building_your_own_iphone_app.php) but still for those of you developing there...I would appreciate any help  sorry if this was too generic..all I want is good direction..

Comment: possible duplicate of [How-to articles for iPhone development, Objective-C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939/how-to-articles-for-iphone-development-objective-c)

Comment: See also [Are you doing iPhone development? How do you learn?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/405568/are-you-doing-iphone-development-how-do-you-learn), [What are the best Cocoa-Touch/iPhone programming blogs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/232570/what-are-the-best-cocoa-touch-iphone-programming-blogs), [Getting Started With iPhone Development](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332039/getting-started-with-iphone-development), [Tips for a successful AppStore submission?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28551/tips-for-a-successful-appstore-submission)

Comment: Thanks a lot..for those links..sorry for being lazy...and not searching it before..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I think that books are a good way to learn. For example, here are a few:
http://www.markj.net/iphone-development-programming-books/

You will need:

An Intel Mac

XCode

A $99 developer fee if you want to actually build for a device/put it on the actual device

Answer (score 1):

I recently started with iPhone app development in school. I read the Head First iPhone book which was a decent start just to get into it. I highly recommend the iPhone lecture series from Stanford University available for free on iTunes U.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Andrew M - but would add that Apple's sample code is a good way to learn by example. You can look at code and reference material without becoming an iOS Developer.
[iOS Reference Library](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/index.html?section=Resource+Types&topic=Getting+Started)

You can do a lot in the iPhone Simulator but at some point you will need to pony up $99 (per year) to start testing on devices.